# Symfony Flex - Doctrine generate entity and entities runtime exception

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-flex

I am testing the new Symfony 4 schema with Flex and I'm having a big trouble while creating a Doctrine Entity or creating the Entity Entities.

In previous versions of Symfony, you can create the entities with the command:

`php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities`

and

`php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities App:MyBundle:MyEntity`

In this version (Symfony 3.3-dev with the new Flex skeleton) the new folder structure "removes" the old Bundle structure, and when executing the above commands to create an Entity in `./src/Entity` it returns and error like this:

> [RuntimeException]
>     Can't find base path for "App\Entity\ExampleEntity" (path: "/mnt/c/.../src/Entity", destination: "/mnt/c/.../src/Entity").

The question is, that is any way to generate an Entity, or the Entity Entities focusing to a path and not with the PSR-4 autoload directive.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Perhaps you've confusing it with the `doctrine:generate:entity` command belong to `SensioGeneratorBundle`? Otherwise, using `App:Entity` should work.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply.

I have generated the entity by hand because when i try to generate a new entity using the `doctrine:generate:entity` it says that AppBundle does not exists (remember that sf with flex "dont use bundles", saves all logic into src folder without any bundle structure.

So when i try `doctrine:generate:entities` and App:Entity it returns

`
[RuntimeException]
  Namespace "App\Entity\Entity:MyEntity" does not contain any mapped entities
`
And the Exception is right because this namespace/file does not exists, the file exists in App\Entity\MyEntity

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Not a fix by any means but a workaround till they catch up. <sup>Very much a cowboy method.</sup>

1. Setup a new project with the standard Symfony file structure.
2. Copy your basic objects into the entity folder.
3. Generate the entitles there `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle`
4. Copy and paste them into your new Symfony Flex project entity folder.
5. Using an IDE do a find and replace in the folder for **AppBundle** with **App**

Sorry, it's far from ideal, but the easiest method I've found rather than having to generate all the getter/setters by hand.

---

## UPDATE: 25/01/2017

As of 4.x the whole idea of `doctrine:generate:entities` [has been dropped](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/729) (In this issue after a long read you'll notice that Doctrine has dropped the commands completely, hence the new Symfony maker bundle).

Apparently, it's viewed as bad practice. Instead, they've released a [new package called maker](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html), which essentially creates the entity class for you but without the getters/setters, and the new suggested practice is to rely on your IDE to auto-generate the Getters and Setters for you.

This works except for the constructor for `ArrayCollections` for `@OneToMany`, but it doesn't take much to add these by hand.

What I've said above is also reflected in the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters).

> ### Generating Getters and Setters
>
> Doctrine now knows how to persist a Product object to the database.
> But the class itself isn't useful yet. All of the properties are
> private, so there's no way to set data on them!
>
> For that reason, you should create public getters and setters for all
> the fields you need to modify from outside of the class. If you use an
> IDE like PhpStorm, it can generate these for you. In PhpStorm, put
> your cursor anywhere in the class, then go to the Code -> Generate
> menu and select "Getters and Setters":

Comment: This method is by far better than the accepted answer.

Comment: Hey Doug! Are you talking about 3.x version to create standard symfony? However, I did try this with current stable version 4.x but it's still generating the exception as mentioned about by Mike. This is really odd that symfony is released without testing this issue. For reference https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/729

Comment: @Sam - I've updated my answer to reflect your question.

Comment: @Doug: Thank you to write in detail. It's helpful and more self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here an other solution.

Temporarily, change Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping:getBasePathForClass

After

```
$namespace = str_replace('\\', '/', $namespace);
```

add:

```
$namespace = str_replace('App/', '', $namespace);
```

Entities will be created in src/App/Entity/. After the copy-paste, remove src/App.

Comment: Hacking to `vendor` directory is definitely not a good solution.